# How do I disable grandpa in polkadot-parachain?

Tags: parachain, rococo, grandpa, rococo-contracts

There is a flag that you can add when running polkadot-parachain

```
      --no-grandpa
          Disable GRANDPA.
          
          Disables voter when running in validator mode, otherwise disable the GRANDPA observer.
```

However, adding this still results in an error when running my node.

```
polkadot-parachain --name contracts --no-grandpa --collator --force-authoring --chain ./e2e/contracts-rococo-1002-rococo-local.json --base-path /tmp/rococo/contracts/data --listen-addr /ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/37913/ws --prometheus-external --rpc-cors all --unsafe-rpc-external --rpc-methods unsafe --prometheus-port 40391 --rpc-port 9919 -lparachain=debug --discover-local -- --execution wasm --chain ./e2e/contracts-rococo-1002-rococo-local.json --port 33571 --rpc-port 43921 --no-grandpa
2024-01-17 11:49:51.167  INFO main sc_cli::runner: Polkadot parachain    
2024-01-17 11:49:51.167  INFO main sc_cli::runner: ✌️  version 1.5.0-a3dc2f15f23    
2024-01-17 11:49:51.167  INFO main sc_cli::runner: ❤️  by Parity Technologies <admin@parity.io>, 2017-2024    
2024-01-17 11:49:51.167  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Chain specification: Contracts on Rococo    
2024-01-17 11:49:51.167  INFO main sc_cli::runner:   Node name: contracts    
2024-01-17 11:49:51.167  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Role: AUTHORITY    
2024-01-17 11:49:51.167  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Database: RocksDb at /tmp/rococo/contracts/data/chains/contracts-rococo/db/full    
CLI parameter `--execution` has no effect anymore and will be removed in the future!
2024-01-17 11:49:53.324  INFO main polkadot_parachain::command: Parachain id: Id(1002)    
2024-01-17 11:49:53.324  INFO main polkadot_parachain::command: Parachain Account: 5Ec4AhPa9NYpwtokA8fbrJW2VgHA8iFYccikJGTf5Cw6NqFT    
2024-01-17 11:49:53.324  INFO main polkadot_parachain::command: Is collating: yes    
2024-01-17 11:49:54.322 DEBUG main parachain::chain-selection: [Relaychain] Using dispute aware relay-chain selection algorithm
2024-01-17 11:49:54.322  INFO main grandpa: [Relaychain]  Loading GRANDPA authority set from genesis on what appears to be first startup.    
Error: Service(Application(Application(Blockchain(Execution(Other("Exported method GrandpaApi_grandpa_authorities is not found"))))))
```

[This comment](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/4224#issuecomment-559154834) suggests that I'll need to remove stuff from node/service.

Can I do this without building polkadot-parachain myself? I'm using a released binary at the moment (`polkadot-parachain 1.5.0-a3dc2f15f23`).